# Error: "Type '(num: number) => number' is not assignable to type 'number'.(2322)"

Tags: typescript, inferred-type

When I have a function like this, I get no complaints:

```js
const roundToTwo = (num: number) => {
  return +(Math.round(+(num + "e+2")) + "e-2");
};
```

When I hover over the function name in VS Code, I can see that it's returning a number: `const roundToTwo: (num: number) => number`.

But when I try to define the return type like this:

```js
const roundToTwo: number = (num: number) => {
  return +(Math.round(+(num + "e+2")) + "e-2");
};
```

I get this error:

```
Type '(num: number) => number' is not assignable to type 'number'.
```

Why is this or what am I doing wrong?

Comment: `const roundToTwo: (num: number) => number = num => { ... }`

Comment: `+(num + "e+2")`? Any advantage over `num * 100` apart from confusing anyone reading your code?

Comment: @Clashsoft, pardon my inexperience. When I tried `return Math.round(num * 100) / 100;` it wouldn't round correctly for me and I couldn't figure out why, but I decided to try again after your comment and it works correctly now. Must be professor aura or something.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're [confused by both the syntax and semantics](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70326208/error-type-num-number-number-is-not-assignable-to-type-number-2322/70327036#comment124316717_70326303), I'm providing a detailed explanation.

### `roundToTwo` is a function type, not a number

Given this defintion:

```js
const roundToTwo = (num: number) => {
  return +(Math.round(+(num + "e+2")) + "e-2")
}
```

this is the actual (and correctly inferred) type of `roundToTwo`:

```js
(num: number) => number
```

Why? Because `roundToTwo` is a [function type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/functions.html#function-type-expressions), not a number. The type is inferred from the function expression being assigned to it. Remember, in Javascript, functions are first class objects. Likewise, in Typescript they are first class types.

### But `const roundToTwo: number` gives it the type `number`

That is what you mistakenly did at the start of your new definition. You said, "roundToTwo is a number" and then you tried to assigned a function to it, getting an expected type error:

```js
const roundToTwo: number = (num: number) => {
  return +(Math.round(+(num + "e+2")) + "e-2")
}

// compare the above to:
const roundToTwo: number = 2
const n: number = 2
```

### There's no need to explicitly type it

It's completely unnecessary to explicitly type `roundToTwo` since you assigned it a function expression immediately, and the inferred type is what you want anyway. Just like you don't need to add `: number` to this declaration:

```js
const max = 42  // same as "const max: number = 42"
```

### If you just wanted to explicitly type *the return value of the function expression*

Place the `:number` after the parameter signature like so:

```js
const roundToTwo = (num: number):number => {
  return +(Math.round(+(num + "e+2")) + "e-2")
}
```

### If you wanted to explicitly type *the `roundToTwo` variable*

You have two options.

The inline syntax:

```js
const roundToTwo: (num: number) => number = (num: number) => {
  return +(Math.round(+(num + "e+2")) + "e-2")
}
```

Using a *type alias*:

```js
type numericFunction = (num: number) => number

const roundToTwo: numericFunction = (num: number) => {
  return +(Math.round(+(num + "e+2")) + "e-2")
}
```

The type alias is more readable especially for more complex function signatures, but more importantly it is very useful if you have to reference this function type elsewhere, e.g. as a function parameter:

```js
function scaleArray(arr: number[], scaleFunc: numericFunction): number {
   
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The error shown is self explanatory. The return type of `roundToTwo` is `(num: number) => number` and not just `number`. When you are already specifying a return type through the function indirectly (Typescript does it though), specifying a primitive directly is not right.

The right way:

```js
const roundToTwo: (num: number) => number = function (num: number) {
  return +(Math.round(+(num + "e+2")) + "e-2");
};
```

Or simply leave it without specifying the type directly. Typescript anyways applies the type since the initialization takes place right at the time of declaration.

Comment: I think I got it, so basically because it's an anonymous function I have to define the whole thing and not just the return type, right?

Comment: Exactly. But in my opinion, that's unnecessary in your case. Anyways, that's how it works.

Comment: @Phil, it does have to  do with being a function, but that it's anonymous is not relevant. I explain it step by step in my answer. Also the multiple ways you can do it shown at the end will help you understand the syntax and semantics better.

Answer (score 0):

try  like this shape

```
 type roundToTwo=(num:number)=>number
 
const roundToTwo :roundToTwo= (num:number)=> {
  return +(Math.round(+(num + "e+2")) + "e-2");
};
```